# Should I say "declutter" or "unclutter"?

Tags: verbs, colloquialisms, prefixes, confusables, un-de

Which verb is more appropriate (and *older*) for clearing out my desk: *declutter* or *unclutter* and ***why***?

> - I should declutter my desk
> - I should unclutter my desk

Dictionary.com defines [**declutter**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/declutter?s=t)

> *verb* (used with object), *verb* (used without object)
>   1. to remove mess or clutter from (a place).

The entry fails to mention its origins but directs us to **[clutter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clutter)**

> Origin 1550-1560; variant of *clotter* (now obsolete), equivalent to
>   *clot* + *-er*

Merriam-Webster for [**unclutter**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unclutter) says:

> *transitive verb*:
>   to remove clutter from:  make neat and orderly, *unclutter the garage*
>
> *First Known Use*  (1930)

Comment: I would use *declutter* for clearing my desk, and (for no reason I can explain besides the fact that it sounds more natural) *unclutter* for clearing my mind of unwanted concerns. This is one of those situations where people's individual preferences probably vary considerably.

Comment: @Erik Sherlock might have problems deciding; he has a mind-palace.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - And there was me thinking it was just another one of those rather ordinary Holmes.

Comment: Yes ... B-rated.

Comment: What, no love for *disclutter*?

Comment: @ErikKowal your instinct is confirmed on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unclutter+your+life%2Cunclutter+your+mind%2Cdeclutter+your+life%2Cdeclutter+your+home&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20home%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20mind%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20home%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: cont'd.  BUT only if you're an American. Astonishingly, there are NO results for British English, which I find very strange, and cannot explain.

Comment: Thank you @ElberichSchneider but your Italian makes me laugh, it's comprehensible though :)

Comment: @ElberichSchneider - it sounds like the Italian spoken by German people...:))

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the two prefixes in question (de- and un-) they are both used to indicate *the opposite of* as in the case of declutter and unclutter.

**[de-](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/de)**
prefix

> - used to add the meaning *'opposite', 'remove', or 'reduce' to a noun or verb:*
>     deforestation
>     the denationalization of the coal industry
>     Once you've written a computer program, you have to debug (= remove the errors from) it.

**[un-](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/un_2)**
prefix

> - used to add the meaning 'not', *'lacking', or 'the opposite of' before adjectives, adverbs, verbs, and nouns:*
>     unrealistic
>     unhappily
>     unscrew
>     unfairness.

Source: www.dictionary.cambridge.org

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unclutter%2Cuncluttered%2Cdeclutter%2Cdecluttered&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunclutter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuncluttered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecluttered%3B%2Cc0) shows that *declutter* is a bit more recent in  usage than  *unclutter* and that they are not very common terms compared to the the adjective 
([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unclutter%2Cuncluttered%2Cdeclutter%2Cdecluttered&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunclutter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuncluttered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecluttered%3B%2Cc0)) **uncluttered.**

According to: www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk

*Declutter* first usage:

> Mr Editor, why not lead a campaign to **de-clutter education**? You would have the support of many Scottish teachers who have had their fill of banking, dairying, ... ”
>   Wednesday 22 November 1944 ,  Dundee Courier ,  Angus, Scotland

[image]
Source:http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/search/results?basicsearch=declutter

I think they are both appropriate  to describe the action of clearing your desk.

Comment: The difference is even more marked with ["declutter your home" and "unclutter your home"](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22declutter+your+home%22&word2=%22unclutter+your+home%22)

Comment: If you could find that newspaper page online, with *de-clutter* you could notify OED and inform them of your discovery. I didn't find anything earlier than **1961** [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=ChwgAQAAMAAJ&q=%22declutter%22&dq=%22declutter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JNUZVKrSJoeh7Abq5oHwDw&redir_esc=y)

Comment: You should notify OED about your discovery, fill in the form here: http://global.oup.com/uk/oedsubform/

Answer (score 3):

First personal opinion, second research (because the research can only be motivated by opinion).

As an AmE speaker, 'uncluttered' seems to me to be the canonical adjective; 'decluttered' sounds a little strange, like someone couldn't remember the usual word and picked a (very reasonable) prefix out of many reasonable ones. A verb to result in that situation (of actively removing a mess) would naturally be 'unclutter', but 'declutter' also sounds like it should work.

Using google as an informal research tool, unclutter existed well before 'declutter', but has [in the past 10 years declined in favor of 'declutter'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unclutter%2C+declutter&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunclutter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%3B%2Cc0).

The OED (online version; behind a security wall) has an entry for 'unclutter' dated to 1930. For 'declutter', there is no entry.

Other online dictionaries seem to have both in equal measure.

Just because everyone uses it doesn't mean it's the standard usage.In informal speech or writing 'declutter' is fine, but in formal usage, **the longer history of 'unclutter' seems to favor it**.

Comment: There are a number of self-help books with the theme of "Declutter your homes" (by the way all American) which are responsible for the spike.

Comment: see this [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unclutter+your+life%2Cunclutter+your+mind%2Cdeclutter+your+life%2Cdeclutter+your+home&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20home%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cunclutter%20your%20mind%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20life%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeclutter%20your%20home%3B%2Cc1)

Answer (score 3):

### The earliest mention of *unclutter*

I found is dated 1922 in a novel entitled *[Saint Theresa](https://archive.org/stream/saintteresaanov00harrgoog#page/n96/mode/2up)* written by the the American novelist, Henry Sydnor Harrison.

> Talk slanted off to the general problem of the records. The expert's
>   plan to set up a separate "dead" file, to help **unclutter** the present
>   broken-down system, proved pleasing to the sales manager who confessed
>   that as the files were now, he was frequently guilty of "holding out" on them. 'T was n't right, but what was a man to do?

This predates Merriam-Webster's aforementioned claim (1930) by a number of years. I would like to know if The Oxford English Dictionary has an older citation.

### Conversely, the earliest citation I found for *declutter*

is dated much later, [1961](http://books.google.it/books?id=ChwgAQAAMAAJ&q=%22declutter%22&dq=%22declutter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JNUZVKrSJoeh7Abq5oHwDw&redir_esc=y), in Volume 129 of *Country Life*

> Action Against Clutter
>
> It has been said that because only abnormal happenings make news, virtue does not qualify for the reporter's attention .... Happily, that is not an absolute truth. An
>   appreciable amount of publicity has been accorded to the fact that the period between June 5 and 12 was **declutter week**, in which a well-organised effort was [rest snipped off]

### And *“de-clutter”*

which pre-dates my reference, [Wednesday 22 November 1944](http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/search/results?basicsearch=declutter), found by @Josh61

I have looked in Etymology Online and in Oxford Dictionaries Online too, neither of these authoritative references provide dates and Etymonline, surprisingly, completely ignores both terms.

---

This leads me to conclude that *unclutter* has the longer history while *declutter* appears to have been coined twenty years later in the United Kingdom.